# FiIlling the ChildItem by clicking the ParentItem in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView which have a list of vehicle data, onClick of each item the list needs to expand and populate the child items with data getting from the server. I was following [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view) tutorial for implementing the expandable recyclerView, but the problem which I am facing now is how to populate childItems from the server onClick of parent item. In the sample code all the data is hardcoded and I tried to google it but couldn't get any feasible solution.

Here is my ParentViewHolder:

```
public class VehicleGenreViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder{
    private TextView day;
    private TextView date;
    private TextView distance;
    private TextView speed;
    private TextView incidents;
    private ImageView arrow;

    public VehicleGenreViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        day = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Day);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Date);
        distance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Distance);
        speed = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Speed);
        incidents = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Incidents);
        arrow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dropDown);
    }

    public void setDay(String value) {
        day.setText(value);
    }

    public void setDate(String value) {
        date.setText(value);
    }

    public void setDistance(String value) {
        distance.setText(value);
    }

    public void setSpeed(String value) {
        speed.setText(value);
    }

    public void setIncidents(String value) {
        incidents.setText(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void expand() {
        animateExpand();
    }

    @Override
    public void collapse() {
        animateCollapse();
    }

    private void animateExpand() {
        RotateAnimation rotate =
                new RotateAnimation(360, 180, RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotate.setDuration(300);
        rotate.setFillAfter(true);
        arrow.setAnimation(rotate);
    }

    private void animateCollapse() {
        RotateAnimation rotate =
                new RotateAnimation(180, 360, RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotate.setDuration(300);
        rotate.setFillAfter(true);
        arrow.setAnimation(rotate);
    }
}
```

ChildViewHolder:

```
public class VehicleGenreDetailViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder{
    private TextView vehicleStatus;
    private TextView vehicleTime;
    private TextView vehicleAddress;

    public VehicleGenreDetailViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        vehicleStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vehicleStatus);
        vehicleTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vehicleTime);
        vehicleAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vehicleAddress);
    }

    public void setVehicleDetailsData(int index,ArrayList<VehicleHistoryDetails> mHistoryDetails){
        vehicleStatus.setText(mHistoryDetails.get(index).getDuration());


    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
  public class VehicleGenreAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<VehicleGenreViewHolder,VehicleGenreDetailViewHolder>{
        public VehicleGenreAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups) {
            super(groups);
        }

        @Override
        public VehicleGenreViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_vehicle_history_list, parent, false);
            return new VehicleGenreViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public VehicleGenreDetailViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_vehicle_history_dropdown, parent, false);
            return new VehicleGenreDetailViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindChildViewHolder(VehicleGenreDetailViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindGroupViewHolder(VehicleGenreViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group) {
            final VehicleHistory vehicleItem = new Gson().fromJson(group.getTitle(),VehicleHistory.class);
            holder.setDate(CommonUtilities.getDateStringFormatted(vehicleItem.getDate(), AppConstants.FORMAT_EEE_DD_MMM_YYYY));
            holder.setDistance(String.valueOf(String.format("%.1f", calcDistance(vehicleItem.getDistance_travelled()))) + " kms");
            holder.setSpeed(String.valueOf(String.format("%.1f", calcSpeed(vehicleItem.getDistance_travelled(), vehicleItem.getMoving_time()))) + " kmph (avg.)");
            holder.setIncidents(String.valueOf(vehicleItem.getTotal_alert_count()) + " incidents");

        }
}
```

Now I wanted to know how do I make a network call to fill the childItem on parentItem click.

Comment: You should get all data initially. Because, in expandable view if you get data by onClick will cause performance issue. Once you have all data, you can inflate that view runtime.

Comment: But how do I know which item user has clicked in the parent list, because the network call will be based on which item is clicked and only the info of that item will be fetched from server.

Comment: In expandable view, generally you should fetch all the parent and children information together. If you fetch children information by onclick parent then this process will takes time to fetch info and then you inflate children with the data. This can break communication with the user.
You should make changes in Network response.